# Strictly enforce ISO8601 date format in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, datetime, serialization, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

**Preamble**

By default the JSON serializer supports the ISO DateTime Standard by the means of the `IsoDateTimeConverter`

With some additional customization we can force that all Datetimes are in UTC (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
```

This again works as expected with `1972-09-18T02:29:12.264513Z` and `1972-09-18T04:29:12.264513+02:00` both equating to `1972-09-18 02:29:12 AM` after serialization.

**Problem**

Unfortunately, however, leaving off the time-zone offset suffix also successfully serializes. So `1972-09-18T04:29:12.264513` equates to `1972-09-18 04:29:12 AM` UTC.

The problem here is that we've made the assumption that the consumer knows about date formats and understands (based on our documentation) that dates are always assumed as UTC.

**The Question**

Is there a way to force the serialization to fail if the time-zone offset suffix is missing so that we are not making any assumptions?

Answer (score 2):

I just looked into Json.NET code and I'm affraid that's not possible (or at least extremly difficult because of need to override `JsonTextReader`/`JsonTextWriter`) to fail if time-zone offset suffix is omitted. All code related to parsing and serializing various data types is internal.

Below are links to places where magic is hapenning:

- Reading DateTime value: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L156
- Parsing date time zone: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/6a22345e28006d74c25e353b6235bc5222bab821/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeParser.cs#L163
- Writing DateTime value https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs#L556

Answer (score 2):

The title of this question should say "Strictly enforce **RFC 3339** date-time ..."

That's because ISO 8601 actually [doesn't require the time-zone designator in the values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators). The format that requires it is [RFC 3339 date-time](https://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/public/rfc/html/rfc3339.html#anchor14). RFC 3339 is a subset of ISO8601 and is also the one used widely over the Internet (JSON Schema, OpenAPI), which is also the RFC 3339's goal: in their own words, the format *"SHOULD be used in new protocols on the Internet"*, and the detailed justification is that *"Since interpretation of an unqualified local time zone will fail in approximately 23/24 of the globe, the interoperability problems of unqualified local time are deemed unacceptable for the Internet."*

---

As for the solution for the Newtonsoft JSON library (and consequently ASP.NET and the many framework that use it nowadays), I have raised [the issue #1631](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1631) to make following the RFC 3339 recommendation simpler but, for now, one [needs to resort to writing their own date time converter](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1631#issuecomment-372183087).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the spec. Date times not denoting the time zone offset should be assumed to be local time:

> If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation,
>   the time is assumed to be in local time. While it may be safe to
>   assume local time when communicating in the same time zone, it is
>   ambiguous when used in communicating across different time zones. It
>   is usually preferable to indicate a time zone (zone designator) using
>   the standard's notation. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates)

Thus it would be best to stick to agreed upon standard. Therefore strictly enforcing the standard would mean I should allow the time zone offset to be left off.